# Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in

Tags: errors

I am having a problem , I am getting this error,
 Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

```
global $wpdb;

$poster_id = $wpdb ->get_results("SELECT ID from wp_posts WHERE post_status='publish' AND post_type='post' AND post_content LIKE '%[gallery%' ORDER BY ID DESC");

$link_sluger = $wpdb ->get_results("SELECT guid FROM wp_posts WHERE post_name LIKE 'albums%' ORDER BY guid DESC");

   foreach ( array_combine($poster_id, $link_sluger) as $posters_id => $linker_slugerr){
        global $post;
        $post = get_post($posters_id->ID);
        $linker_sluger = $linker_slugerr->guid;

            if(has_shortcode( $post->post_content, 'gallery' ) ){

                echo'<div class="single-album home-last-gallery col-md-4 col-sm-12"> <a href="'.$linker_sluger.'">';
                echo na_get_gallery_image_urls($posters_id->ID, $linker_sluger); 
                echo '</a></div>';

             }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved it. Just change:

```
foreach( $poster_id as $index => $posterss_id ) {
    global $post;
    $post = get_post( $posterss_id->ID );
    $linker_sluger = $link_sluger[$index]->guid; 
    /* ... */
}
```

Full Solution:

```
global $wpdb;

$poster_id      = $wpdb ->get_results( "SELECT ID from wp_posts WHERE post_status='publish' AND post_type='post' AND post_content LIKE '%[gallery%' ORDER BY ID DESC" );
$link_sluger    = $wpdb ->get_results("SELECT guid FROM wp_posts WHERE post_name LIKE 'albums%' ORDER BY guid DESC");

foreach( $poster_id as $index => $posterss_id ) {

    global $post;
    $post = get_post($posterss_id->ID);
    $linker_sluger= $link_sluger[$index]->guid;

    if( has_shortcode( $post->post_content, 'gallery' ) ){

        echo'<div class="single-album home-last-gallery col-md-4 col-sm-12"> <a href="'.$linker_sluger.'">';
        echo na_get_gallery_image_urls($posterss_id->ID, $linker_sluger); 
        echo '</a></div>';

    }

}
```

Comment: i solved it just change:
foreach ( $poster_id as $index => $posterss_id){
                                            global $post;
                                            $post = get_post($posterss_id->ID);
                                            $linker_sluger= $link_sluger[$index]->guid;

Comment: Please use the [**edit**](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/345007/edit) link below your question if you would like to add further information.

Comment: Please look into editing your questions and formatting your code so it's easier for other users to read. https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189/322985